# Identify the owner and license carrier for libmono-btls-shared.so which is injected when building an android application using Xamarin.android

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, mono

How to identify who is the owner and license carrier for "libmono-btls-shared.so" which is injected when building an android application using Xamarin.android.

There are few more Iso files also like "libSkiaSharp.so",libwebp.so","libmono-native.so"

Comment: Microsoft is the "owner"

Comment: what is the license

Comment: Unclear why you didn't find: https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/main/LICENSE and https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-android/blob/main/LICENSE but you may be served by checking each open-source project for their respective license.